# How to find equation of a graph using vertical asymptote?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czgKW.png)

Based on the graph, I need to find the equation.
What I know: vertical asymptote x = 4, and opening at x = -4.
I am struggling to find the rational function of the graph. y = 1/-x+4 is what I have currently, but I don`t know how to include the opening to the equation. What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "opening"?

Comment: if you look at the graph, the line above the x = -4 is open, I am guessing the value is excluded

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ look similar to this. We can start from here.

The graph moved $4$ units to the right and $1$ unit up.

So, $\displaystyle f(x)= \frac{1}{x-4} + 1 = \frac{x-3}{x-4}$ is almost the same as your graph.

Finally, either you can say that $\displaystyle f: \mathbb R \backslash\{-4\} \to \mathbb R$ for the "opening" (you can call it removable discontinuity) and say $\displaystyle f(x)= \frac{x-3}{x-4}$

**or**

You can say $\displaystyle f(x)=\left( \frac{x-3}{x-4}\right)\cdot \left( \frac{x+4}{x+4} \right)= \frac{x^2+x-12}{x^2-16}$ and then it will be "obvious" that the function is not defined on $x=-4$ and thus has a removable discontinuity.

Answer (score 0):

I would say $$f(x) = \frac{x+4}{x+4} - \frac{1}{x-4}$$ for $x\neq  \pm 4$ is more accurate than the other answer. This gives the appropriate values $f(0)=1\frac14$ and $f(5)=0$, and the function is increasing everywhere.

Note that the first term is intentionally unreduced so that its value is $1$ everywhere except at $x=-4$ where it is undefined (thus producing the "opening").